# Botão não consegue marca rádio button nem fazer right em div

Tags: jquery, css, css3

bom dia!

Tenho o script abaixo que está com duas falhas:

1. Quando clico nos **botões** os **radio buttons** não estão sendo marcados
2. Ao clicar no botão da direita, a bolinha caminha ara a esquerda e muda o texto. Era isso o esperado.
   Mas, quando clico no botão da esquerda, apenas o texto está mudando mas a bolinha não está ind para a direita!

Onde estou errando?

```js
    $("div.btnyesno > button#sim").click(function() {
        $("div.btnyesno > div#containerbtn > div#label")
               .css("right", "5px")
               .html("Não");
        //$("div.btnyesno > input[type=radio][id=bloq]").prop("checked", true);
    });
    $("div.btnyesno > button#nao").click(function() {   
        $("div.btnyesno > div#containerbtn > div#label")
               .css("left", "5px")
               .html("Sim");
        //$("div.btnyesno > input[type=radio][id=desbloq]").prop("checked", true);
        
    });
```

```css
    div.btnyesno > input[type="radio"] {
        display: none;
    }
    div.btnyesno {
        position:relative;
        display: flex;
        width: 200px;
        height: 70px;
    }
    div.btnyesno > div#containerbtn {
        position:relative;
        display: flex;;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 500px;
    }
    div.btnyesno > div#containerbtn > div#label {
        position:absolute;
        display: flex;
        right: 5px;
        width: 45px;
        height:45px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 500px;
        transition: all 500ms;
    }
    div.btnyesno > button{
        position:relative;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 50px;
        height:50px;
    }
    div.btnyesno  > button#sim {
        left: -10px;
    }
    div.btnyesno  > button#nao {
        right: -10px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btnyesno">
    <input type="radio" name="bloq" id="bloq">
    <button for="bloq" id="sim">Sim</button>
    <div id="containerbtn"> 
      <div id="label">Não</div>
    </div>
    <button for="desbloq" id="nao">Não</button>
    <input type="radio" name="bloq" id="desbloq">
</div>
```

Após a explicação do Hugo estou tentando fazer sem o JS mas encontrei outro problema.

Na abordagem abaixo,

```css
    div.btnyesno > input[type="radio"] {
        display: none;
    }
    div.btnyesno {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        width: 200px;
        height: 70px;
    }
    div.btnyesno > div#containerball {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 500px;
    }
    div.btnyesno > div#containerball > div#ball {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        left: 50px;
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        background: #ccc;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border-radius: 500px;
        transition: all 500ms;
    }
    div.btnyesno > label{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    div.btnyesno > label#sim {
        left: -10px;
    }
    div.btnyesno > label#nao {
        right: -10px;
    }
    #bloq:checked ~ #label {
      left: 5px !important;
    }
    #desboq:checked ~ #label {
      right: 5px !important;
    }       
    .btnYes {
        left: 5px !important;
    }
    .btnNo {
        right: 5px !important;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="btnyesno">
        <input type="radio" name="bloq" id="bloq" value="bloq">
        <input type="radio" name="bloq" id="desbloq" value="desbloq" checked>
        <label role="button" for="bloq" id="sim">Sim</label>
        <div id="containerball">    
          <div id="ball"></div>
        </div>
        <label role="button" for="desbloq" id="nao">Não</label>
    </div>
```

a bolinha não mais muda a posição.

Mas o input recebe o click do label.

Comment: `$("div.btnyesno > button#sim")` pq fazer esse seletor tão complexo? o ID **deve ser único**, então basta fazer `$("#sim")`, o mesmo vale para os outros

Comment: @RicardoPontual, obrigado pela dica, faz todo sentido. Acho que vou seguir. Mas, e o problema? Sabe como me ajudar a resolver?

Comment: coloquei  numa resposta para ficar mais fácil de visualizar

Answer (score 1):

Cara nem precisa de JS para fazer isso, muito menos de jQuery, só com CSS vc resolve tudo.

O texto vc troca usando o *pseudo-elemento* `::after`, o botão não tem o atributo `for` como vc usou, para isso usa uma `label` que aceita o `for`, e coloque nela o `role="button"` para dar semântica.

Depois use o *seletor adjacente* `~` para a regra CSS ativar os elementos correspondentes ao clicar na `label` (clicando na `laber` com `for` vc ativa o `radio` com o `ID` correspondente)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código da imagem acima:**

```css
div.btnyesno > input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

div.btnyesno {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
}

div.btnyesno > div#containerbtn {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  ;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  ;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 500px;
}

div.btnyesno > div#containerbtn > div#label {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  right: 5px;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 500px;
  transition: all 500ms;
}

div.btnyesno > label {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div.btnyesno > label#sim {
  left: -10px;
}

div.btnyesno > label#nao {
  right: -10px;
}

/* correções */
#bloq:checked ~ #sim,
#desbloq:checked ~ #nao{
  background-color: red;
}
#bloq:checked ~ #containerbtn > #label {
  left: 5px !important;
}

#label::after {
  content: "não";
}
#bloq:checked ~ #containerbtn > #label::after {
  content: "sim";
}
```

```html
<div class="btnyesno">
  <input type="radio" name="bloq" id="bloq">
  <input type="radio" name="bloq" id="desbloq">
  <label for="bloq" id="sim" role="button">Sim</label>
  <div id="containerbtn">
    <div id="label"></div>
  </div>
  <label for="desbloq" id="nao" role="button">Não</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Olha, CSS não é o meu forte. Mas tenho uma dúvida aqui. O **radio-button**, após submetido o formulário, terá o valor do **label** selecionado?

Comment: Sim @CarlosRocha , acredito que sim! Input é ligado ao Label correspondente, e não a Div com o texto nesse caso.

Comment: Então, estou tentando fazer igual ao teu mas estou com um problema. Ao retirar o JS, a bolinha  não muda de posição, Parece que o for do **span** não está funcionando.. Vou colocar o novo código no fina da pergunta

Comment: @CarlosRocha que `span` mano?? Na sua pegunta nem tem a tag `<span>`. Na moral, da até desgosto de responder as suas pergunta, vc não consegue copiar um código cara.... se aqui funciona pq ai não funciona? Vc não tem ideia do que está fazendo, agora trocou sem nenhum motivo aparente o elemento Label por um Span, sendo que o atributo `for` não funciona no `span`... mano na boa, vai com a resposta do colega Ricardo,eu acredito que vc não tem condições de lidar com essa resposta

Comment: Entendo sua preocupação @hugo. Mas é que não sou muito de copiar. Eu gosto de entender o que estou fazendo. Mas está d boa. Grarto pela atenção!

Comment: não querendo ser chato mas sendo. Me explica só uma coisa: No código: #bloq:checked ~ #containerbtn > #label {
  left: 5px !important;
}, você está clicando no label que bloqueia e ativando o input. Ok. Entendido. Mas não tem no código um clique no label de desbloq. No entanto, a bolinha core do mesmo jeito. Me explica isso e estará ótimo para mim,

Comment: O padrão é a direita (right), vc mesmo definiu isso aqui `div.btnyesno > div#containerbtn > div#label { right: 5px;` ... } então o Right já está valendo por padrão. Quando vc marca o Radio do bloqueio ele coloca o Left, quando vc marca o outro Radio o Left sai e o "padrão" Right que fica valendo

Comment: Então, eu editei a parte de baixo da minha pergunta mantendo a pergunta original. Só apaguei a parte que foi o alvo da bronca que você me deu! Mas tem alguma coisa errado e não consigo achar de jeito nenhum. Tecnicamente pela explicaçao do comentário anteior, era para estar funcinando

Answer (score 0):

Seu código, além do detalhe dos seletores que mencionei antes, tem vários pontos de melhoria no CSS e javascript.

Vou comentar aqui alguns pontos:

- Simplificar o seletor por ID;
- Adicionar classes CSS para posicionar o elemento e fazer a mudança entre essas classes no lugar de fazer isso com `javascript`;
- Se quer só posicionar o elemento, pode usar só a propriedade `left`, deixe zero para ficar à esquerda e um valor positivo pra descolocar mais "para a direita", não há necessidade de usar `right`.

Veja aqui um exemplo:

```js
$("#sim").click(function() {
  $("#label")
     .removeClass("nao")
     .addClass("sim");
});
    
$("#nao").click(function() {   
    $("#label")
       .removeClass("sim")
       .addClass("nao");
});
```

```css
div.btnyesno > input[type="radio"] {
        display: none;
    }
    div.btnyesno {
        position:relative;
        display: flex;
        width: 200px;
        height: 70px;
    }
 #containerbtn {
        position:relative;
        display: flex;;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 500px;
    }
#containerbtn > div#label {
        position:absolute;
        display: flex;
        right: 5px;
        width: 45px;
        height:45px;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 500px;
        transition: all 500ms;
    }
    div.btnyesno > button{
        position:relative;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 50px;
        height:50px;
    }

   .sim {
     left: 0;
     
   }
   .sim:before {
     content: "Sim";
   }

   .nao {
    left: 50px;
   }
   
   .nao:before {
     content: "Não";
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btnyesno">
    <input type="radio" name="bloq" id="bloq">
    <button for="bloq" id="sim">Sim</button>
    <div id="containerbtn"> 
      <div id="label"class="nao"></div>
    </div>
    <button for="desbloq" id="nao">Não</button>
    <input type="radio" name="bloq" id="desbloq">
</div>
```

Aproveitei e setei também o `content` com Sim/Não baseado na class, assim não precisa mudar nada no `javascript`, apenas as classes, que resolvem tudo o resto